# Handling binary data with marshmallow (JSON) + SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, json, flask, sqlalchemy, marshmallow

#### Architecture:

vue.js (frontend) <--> {JSON} <--> Flask (backend) <--> {marshmallow} <--> {SQLAlchemy} <--> Postgres (db)

#### Description:

I am implementing way to query records (multiple attributes, one including binary images) from database for vue.js render. I chose to store images in binary (no base64).

When I want to keep JSON as standard way for frontend communication, binary image needs to be converted to base64, together with other text-based attribute values in database record.

#### Question:

Normally, the code goes as below.
Binary content in fetched record breaks the serialization. Is there way to intercept in between, base64 the fetched binary data, thereby forming valid JSON?

I just want to explore this possibility, before considering alternative of storing images in database as base64 to begin with. Kind of - eat the cake and have it too.

How to go about this?

```
# SQLA - lookup in DB
session = Session()
recsList = session.query(Entity).all()

# marshmallow - JSON serialize
entity_schema = EntitySchema()
respJsonObj = entity_schema.dump(recsList) # <- JSON serialization breaks for binary images 
respJson = jsonify(respJsonObj)

session.close()
```

Info: For *creation* of same records, including images, I used `multipart/form-data`, where JSON issue doesn't arise.

PS: Please ignore the 'why-storing-images-in-db', not the focus here.

Comment: Create a custom BinaryField and implement base64 encoding/decoding in its serialization/deserialization methods.